# Javascript select option after change won't update when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come up against some weird behaviour that I can't seem to get working correctly. I have a book button where it would select the value from the dropdown which works fine. However the issues arises when the user decides to select something from the dropdown and then changes their mind and uses the button. The button then won't update the changed value within the dropdown. I figured this had to do something with the selected behaviour being turned to true, I tried to loop through the options and set them to false but it didn't fix the issue. Any advice?

JS

```
$(".book-btn").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#id_CourseName :selected').attr('selected',false);
  var courseTitle = $(this).parent().parent().children(".course-title-ref")[0].innerText;
  $(`#id_CourseName option:contains(${courseTitle})`).attr('selected', true);
});

$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("#id_CourseName").change(function(e){
    for(let i=0 ; i<$('#id_CourseName').length; i++){
      $('#id_CourseName').eq(i).attr('selected',false);
      }

  })
})
```

Edit

For the HTML I'm using Django to render out the options of the dropdown

```
 <label for="">Service/Course</label>
 {{ form.CourseName }}
```

Comment: at which plce is your js inside the html page?

Comment: can you show html code as well?

Comment: Edit made, I'm using Django to render out the dropdown information which is partially why I might be having issues with it. The id of the select becomes #id_CourseName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use loop just to remove `selected` .Instead only write your selected true or false inside your button handler.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".book-btn").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#id_CourseName option:selected').prop('selected', false);
  var courseTitle = "1"; //just for demo...
  $(`#id_CourseName option:contains(${courseTitle})`).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id_CourseName">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<button class="book-btn">Book</button>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, may I ask as to why the .attr and .prop behave differently even though they were both changing the selected value?

Comment: Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to know difference between them :) .